# Reading .csv data from URL in python: extra lines

Tags: python, url, csv, codec

First post on stackoverflow, and a newbie to python. I'm trying to read weather data from a location from wunderground. It should be straightforward:

```
import csv
import urllib2   
url = 'http://www.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXDailyHistory.asp?ID=KMDLAURE4&day=9&month=6&year=2013&graphspan=day&format=1'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
cr = csv.reader(response)
```

However, when I do this, I get an extra line in between all the data. So if I examine the first few lines of the .csv output, I get the following:

```
    cr.next()
    Out[210]: []

    cr.next()
    Out[211]: 
    ['Time',
   blah blah blah fields redacted
     'DateUTC<br>']

    cr.next()
    Out[212]: 
    ['2013-06-09 00:07:00',
      blah blah blah data redacted
     '2013-06-09 04:07:00',
     '']

    cr.next()
    Out[213]: ['<br>']

    cr.next()
    Out[214]: 
    ['2013-06-09 00:22:00',
     blah blah blah data redacted,
     '2013-06-09 04:22:00',
     '']
```

I could just loop over the file, and throw away every other line, or check to see if the line only contains < br > and get rid of it. To me, that's an inelegant solution, as the real 'problem' is due to the reading of the text. This seems like an 'opening in binary' or codec problem, but how do I check? Thanks!

Comment: If you get `<br>` in your result then it is HTML file not (correct) CSV file.

Comment: This kind of sucks. I checked out the website. It looks like it is returning csv data but the content type is wrong, which is why you get the formatting(<br>) and such when you open the url. Looks like you will just have to loop over your data and ignore/remote the tags that are causing the problem.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be a wunderground API call, which are discussed here: http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/.  That API returns either XML or JSON, but not CSV.

Comment: Right. I was trying to avoid the API as that seems (to me) to be more for grabbing realtime forecast data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a way to tell wunderground to return a true CSV format, instead of HTML. However, you can work around it by skipping those rows that are too short:

```
import csv
import urllib2   
url = 'http://www.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXDailyHistory.asp?ID=KMDLAURE4&day=9&month=6&year=2013&graphspan=day&format=1'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
cr = csv.reader(response)

for row in cr:
    if len(row) <= 1: continue
    print row
```

## Update

Here is a different approach: create a class to filter out those unwanted lines:

```
import csv
import urllib2   

class RemoveBlank(object):
    def __init__(self, response):
        self.response = response
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        line = '\n'
        while line == '\n' or line == '<br>\n':
            line = next(self.response)
        return line

url = 'http://www.wunderground.com/weatherstation/WXDailyHistory.asp?ID=KMDLAURE4&day=9&month=6&year=2013&graphspan=day&format=1'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
cr = csv.reader(RemoveBlank(response))

for row in cr:
    print row
```

This time, instead of giving the response object to `cdv.reader`, you wrap that response object within the `RemoveBlank` object. Note that in Python 3, the method should be named `__next__`.

The advantage of this method: it leaves the main body clean so you can concentrate on your logic.

Comment: Brilliant. This worked like a charm. I understand the last part of the class, that is, while the line is either blank or contains only <br>\n, you set that line equal to the next line (which is presumably filled). What's the reasoning behind making removeblank a class vs just defining the functions?

Comment: I need a class to hold on to the response object.

Answer (score 0):

**First of all, this isn't an answer for your question. This is an alternative solution using a different way to solve the problem.**

I use the same API, and a better way to get the same info is use the JSON response as [Larry Lustig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180368/larry-lustig) has commented.

```
from json import loads
from urllib import urlopen

url = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/01f4106be8822ff4/history_201300609/q/MD/Laurel.json'
response = loads(urlopen(url).read())

print 'Date', 'Temperature', 'Dew Point', 'Umidity' 
for w in response['history']['observations']:
    print w['date']['pretty'], w['tempi'], w['dewpti'], w['hum']
```

Response

```
Date Temperature Dew Point Umidity
12:15 AM EST on January 29, 2013 32.0 32.0 100
12:36 AM EST on January 29, 2013 32.0 32.0 100
12:57 AM EST on January 29, 2013 32.0 32.0 100
1:18 AM EST on January 29, 2013 32.0 32.0 100
1:39 AM EST on January 29, 2013 32.0 32.0 100
```

In official API [doc](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=data/history&MR=1) you could found more info.

**And here, the solution for your problem. This is a way to read a CSV file as a dictionary.**

```
from urllib import urlopen
from csv import DictReader
from StrinIO import StringIO

url = 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/01f4106be8822ff4/history_201300609/q/MD/Laurel.json'
response = StringIO(urlopen(url).read())
weather = DictReader(response)

# Skips header
weather.next()

for w in weather:
    print w
```

Response

```
{None: ['2013-06-09 00:07:00', '18.5', '17.2', '1015.8', 'WNW', '285', '0.0', '-1607.4', '92', '-2539.7', '', '', '0.0', 'weatherlink.com 1.10', '2013-06-09 04:07:00', '']}
{None: ['<br>']}
{None: ['2013-06-09 00:22:00', '18.6', '17.8', '1015.8', 'WNW', '285', '0.0', '-1607.4', '93', '-2539.7', '', '', '0.0', 'weatherlink.com 1.10', '2013-06-09 04:22:00', '']}
```

Here again, your results comes as dict. Easier to handle.

Comment: I like your use of the API. Thanks! If I don't use this now, I will eventually use it. However, when I run the top bit of code, it fails on the 'print w' statement, with the error 'TypeError: string indices must be integers'